# A fast question about kerberos and Oracle

Tags: oracle, kerberos

I'm configuring Kerberos on Oracle I have 2 machines, one is a server with Oracle DB, the other is a client with oracle client(basic+sqlplus), my sqlnet.ora is like this(on server)

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (BEQ, TCPS, KERBEROS5, NONE)
SQLNET.FALLBACK_AUTHENTICATION=TRUE
SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CONF_MIT = TRUE
ADR_BASE = /var/oracle/app
SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CC_NAME = /tmp/krb5cc_<uid>
SQLNET.KERBEROS5_KEYTAB = /etc/oracle.keytab
SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CLOCKSKEW = 1200
SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CONF=/etc/krb5.conf
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_KERBEROS5_SERVICE=myservice
```

The keytab is ok, the configuration work and oracle user can access it

```
sqlplus /@myserver.domain/myservice

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Apr 12 05:41:58 2022
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Last Successful login time: Tue Apr 12 2022 05:26:22 +02:00

Connected to:
Oracle Database 21c Enterprise Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 21.3.0.0.0
    
    SQL> select sys_context('userenv','authentication_method') from dual;

SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','AUTHENTICATION_METHOD')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
KERBEROS
```

The problem is on client.
I have copied the sqlnet.ora(is identical to the server) in the right place
I did kinit(I don't have okinit in the client) and...

```
sqlplus /@myserver.domain/myservice

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Tue Apr 12 05:43:44 2022
Version 21.5.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied


Enter user-name:
```

I have configured the user correctly(on the server the kerberos user can enter without problems), what I miss in the client?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: the client needs the [Oracle Advanced Security](https://www.oracle.com/us/products/database/ds-security-advanced-security-11gr2-1-129479.pdf)
option to connect using kerberos auth.
Is included in Enteprise Edition(server) but must be(if you want to use kerberos) buy separately for clients.